# C++ Splitting a char string into a dynamic char array behaving unpredictably

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, char, split

I have a program creating a dynamic char string of data inputs (c++ string is not allowed to use) that look like this (where instead of the date can be basically any other data and the number of data blocks is not given):

> 2004-01-18|2005-01-18|

What I need to do with the string is to split it into a 2d char array of singular data blocks that I can use for printing. The code I have looks like this:

```
char** CRegister::Split(char *st, int& parts, int& maxChars) const{

    parts = 0;
    maxChars = 0;
    int maxtmp = 0;
    int j = 0; 

    /* Calculating the number of data blocks in the string */

    while(st[j]){
        if(st[j] == '|'){
            parts++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    j = 0; 

    /* Calculating the longest data block length for array initialization */

    while(st[j]){
        if(st[j] != '|'){
            maxtmp++;
        }
         else{
            if(maxtmp > maxChars){
                maxChars = maxtmp;
            }
            maxtmp = 0;
         }
        j++;
    }
    j = 0; 

    cout << "!!!!!-----!!!!!-" << st << "-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!" << endl;

    /* Initialization of the dara array */

    char **array = new char*[parts];
    for(int i = 0; i < parts; i++){
        array[i] = new char[maxChars];
    }

    /* Filling the array with data blocks */

    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < parts; i++){
        while(st[j] != '|'){
            array[i][p] = st[j];
            j++;
            p++;
        }
        if(st[j] == '|'){
            j++;
        }
        p = 0;
    }    
    return array;    
}
```

From the most part it works just the way I need it to, but the problem is it tends to behave unpredictably at times, ruining the whole program - the blocks of data aren't ended where they are supposed to and a bunch of other characters is added to it (most often parts of the previously used words). The result then looks like this (with the line between "!!!!!-----!!!!!-" being the pre-processed array)

```
!!!!!-----!!!!!-2003-01-18|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!
!!!!!-----!!!!!-Whiston's street|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!
!!!!!-----!!!!!-Miami|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!

2003-01-18 Whiston's street Miami

!!!!!-----!!!!!-2004-01-18|2005-01-18|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!
!!!!!-----!!!!!-Whiston's street|Someone's streetz|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!
!!!!!-----!!!!!-Miami|Siberia|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!  

2004-01-18 Whiston's street Miami
2005-01-18street Someone's streetz Siberia

!!!!!-----!!!!!-2004-01-18|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!
!!!!!-----!!!!!-Whiston's street|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!
!!!!!-----!!!!!-Miami|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!

2004-01-18 Whiston's street Miami

!!!!!-----!!!!!-2004-01-18|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!
!!!!!-----!!!!!-Whiston's street|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!
!!!!!-----!!!!!-Miami|-!!!!!!!-----!!!!!

2004-01-18streetz Whiston's street Miami
```

The function is called three times in a row for the three different sets of data that are then printed in a row.

Comment: "c++ string is not allowed to use" is this homework? (needs homework tag then)

Comment: @Rookie: The [tag:homework] tag was removed *long* ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the standard string class, write a simplified version of your own, and use that.

Then do roughly the same with `std::vector` -- either use it, or write a simplified version of your own.

When you have both of those done, writing this function to parse the input into a `my_vector<my_string>` should border on utterly trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately vector is not allowed either and I'm not familiar with it anyway, so I can't write it. Plus I have the whole program already done and working, so that would mean many more hours of work I can't afford :(... Suppose I will just have to figure out what's wrong with this one.